# web.py obtain request headers

Tags: python, web.py

im starting with python and web.py

im trying to build a REST api with it.
i know hoy to use the basics of web.py
but i still can figure a way to get the Content-Type of a request
i got this post function defined:

```
  def POST(self,name):
        ct=web.ctx.env.get('Content-Type')
        return json.dumps({ 'body' : web.data(),'ct':ct } )
```

im trying to get the body data and the content type bit ct ends null

```
curl -H 'Accept: application/json' localhost:8080/test -d '{"a":"b"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

outputs

```
{"body": "{\"a\":\"b\"}", "ct": null}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`web.ctx.env`](http://webpy.org/cookbook/ctx) structure gives you access to the [WSGI environment variable](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/#environ-variables). In WSGI apps, the content type header is named `CONTENT_TYPE`:

```
ct = web.ctx.env.get('CONTENT_TYPE')
```